# Korean Math Olympiad 1993 (geometry)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

Consider a $\triangle ABC$ with $BC = a$, $CA = b$, $AB = c$. Let $D$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and $E$ be the intersection of the bisector of $A$ with $BC$. The circle through $A$, $D$, $E$ meets $AC$, $AB$ again at $F$, $G$ respectively. Let $H \neq B$ be a point on $AB$ with $BG = GH$. Prove that $\triangle EBH $ and $\triangle ABC$ are similar and ﬁnd the ratio of their areas.

As far as I can go, $\triangle{BAE}\sim\triangle{BDG}\sim\triangle{BCH}$, $\triangle{CEF}\sim\triangle{CAD}$...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$BG\cdot BA=BD\cdot BE$ $~\Longrightarrow$ $~2BG\cdot BA=2BD\cdot BE$ $~\Longrightarrow$ $~BH\cdot BA=BC\cdot BE$
thus, $\square AHEC$ is cyclic and $\triangle EBH\sim\triangle ABC$
the similarity ratio is $\dfrac{BE}{BA}=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{ac}{b+c}\right)}{c}=\dfrac{a}{b+c}$ and then area ratio is $\dfrac{a^{2}}{(b+c)^{2}}$

Comment: Smart! The key is to double BG and BD!

Answer (score 1):

Join *HC* in the given diagram.

Quad. $AGDE$ is cyclic => $\measuredangle BDG = \frac{\measuredangle A}{2}$.

Clearly, $BG = HG$ and $BD = DC$ => $GD || HC$ (by the midpoint theorem.)

=> $\measuredangle HCE = \measuredangle BDG = \frac{\measuredangle A}{2}$ => Quad. $AHEC$is cyclic. => $\measuredangle HEB  = \measuredangle A$.

But $\measuredangle EBH = \measuredangle ABC $(Common) => triangle $EBH$ ~ triangle $ABC$.

Ar. triangle $EBH$ / Ar. triangle $ABC$ = Square of ratio of their corresponding sides.

=> Ar. triangle $EBH$ / Ar. triangle $ABC$ = $\left(\frac{EB }{AB}\right)^2 = [{ac/(b+c)} / c]^2
= (b+c)^2 / a^2$.

....Member at Brilliant.org

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use proper formatting and mathjax typesetting. Your post is hard to read. And by the way, what's the difference between this one and the accepted answer?